# GridView not coming up Full Screen in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am implementing my own Calendar strangely the gridView is not coming up fully. I am the numbers are coming properly but the screen is not full. It is half. I would like to implement something similar to CalendarView.

Please check the snapshot you will understand:

[image]

can you see the lot of empty grey Space. How do make it such way it is full screen?

Here are two xml's that are related to Calendar

**CalendarView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendarMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next is CalendarItems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_cell"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textvaluedate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:textColor="#F44336"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try to change everything match_parent still the same. I am not really sure where I am going wrong here?

Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 2:**

I have updated my code according to **@Heshan Sandeepa**. I got the full screen but the image box look really big. Please take a look at the screen shot. What could be wrong here?

Here is the CODE in my Baseadapter:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, month.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        int numDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);

        double rowCounts = Math.ceil(numDays/7);
        int rowCount = (int) rowCounts;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {  
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
        }

        v.setMinimumHeight(height / rowCount);
}
```

All I require is that I need bigger square box for each date. That is all.

[image]

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but you should try setting layout weight on the calendar items, so that they fill as much space as needed.

Comment: How? I mean the Calendar Items are dynamically added right?

Comment: Something like `android:layout_weight="1"` in your CalendarItems xml Linearlayout might work.

Comment: trying out.... Hope it works.

Comment: @JonasCz: Tried it.. Didn't work. :(

Comment: Try to remove `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` and set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in GridView

Comment: @Rami: Tried just now still the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

For columns you can achieve above requirement through  strechMode [read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setStretchMode(int)) . For rows you can achieve this through following steps ,

1. Calculate the Device height.

   ```
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(new DisplayMetrics());
   int deviceHeight = new DisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
   ```
2. Reduce the action bar height / any paddings from that (if you have one)
3. You can determine how many rows you need, then you can define the height of each row(cell actually) . You can get the row number by deviding the number of days of relevant month by 7 and get the ceiling value.

   ex - jan

   ```
   int rowCount = Math.ceil(31/7);
                = 5
   ```

   ex - Feb (carefull, here  no need to get the ceiling as you can get integer)

   ```
   int rowCount = Math.ceil(28/7);
                = 4
   ```

Same for all months.

4. Now you have screen height(step 2) and the number of row(step 3), so can define what is the exact height of each ro. I hope you are having an adapter and custom view for each cell.
   When you are inflating the custom view at the getView() ,  define the calculated height as the minimum height.

   ```
   your_view.setMinimumHeight(<device height / rowCount>)
   ```

Comment: It is a calendar: So Sun to Sat is best to show 7 Columns right?

Comment: Hey! Sorry I was travelling and couldn't work your new logic. I applied it just today and got the full screen but take a look the screen shot. It is looks really huge. What could be wrong here? I mean I want to get Bigger square box for each number. I have updated my question with SNAP Shot

Comment: you haven't calculated the correct height i think. Which month you tried ?

Comment: I tried for april. I did exactly like what you told me to do